# Auto Increment field in NodeJS and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am working on NodeJS

While inserting the data into MongoDB database with the help of NodeJS and Mongoose, I am getting the object Id which is more then 24-digit long.

I want to provide id like 1, 2, 3 4....which is nothing a auto increment digit.

Kindly help me to solve this puzzle.

Comment: MongoDB doesn't support this OOB, you can however use plugins to achieve it, like https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-auto-increment

Comment: Can we achieve through JSON, where we mention our schema in Model files.

Answer (score 0):

By default MongoDB does not support auto-increment sequence as a default feature like some relational databases.

But you can implement using Triggers. I found this official guide: https://www.mongodb.com/basics/mongodb-auto-increment

Answer (score 0):

Find the below solutions with mongoose-sequence.

This plugin lets you create fields which autoincrement their value:

every time a new document is inserted in a collection
or
when you explicitly want to increment them
This increment can be:

global: every document has a unique value for the sequence field
scoped: the counter depends on the value of other field(s)
Multiple counters can be set for a collection.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).